# Stringstream string to integer conversion in C++

Tags: c++, stringstream

I just read about stringstream in C++ and implemented a simple program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    stringstream sso;
    string str;

    //integer to string
    cin >> num;
    sso << num;
    sso >> str;
    cout << "String form of number : " << str << endl;

    //string to integer
    cin >> str;
    sso << str;
    sso >> num; //num still has value from previous integer to string????
    cout << "Integer form of string (+2) :" << (num + 2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output :

```
12
String form of number : 12
44
Integer form of string (+2) :14
```

I am getting incorrect output as `num` is not getting updated and still holding the old value from previous calculation. What's the silly mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clear the stringstream between use because the eofbit has been set during the first use:

```
sso.clear();
sso.str("");
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But when I did `sso << str;` second time in `string to integer`, do `sso` hold both the values : current as well as previous streams?

Comment: @InsaneCoder think it should fail and just retain the previous value (12)

Comment: Yes, it is failing. I put a check as per answer by @Ulrich and confirmed it. Thanks Jerome and Ulrich

Answer (score 4):

After the first input operation, the stringstream gets its EOF-bit set. This bit is sticky, i.e. it doesn't get erased by adding more input to parse. As a general rule, when you read data, you should also verify that reading was successful. For streams, you can check the stream state using this:

```
if(!(istream >> value)) throw runtime_error("reading failed");
```

I'm pretty sure your second input operation simply fails, at which point the value retains its former value.